Fetch of mp3 embedded file on ios with capacitor gives http result code 0 but otherwise succeeds
Context is ionic/capacitor 6.2 deployed to ios device via xcode.
The basic problem is that a http get (fetch) of an mp3 file completes with a http status code of 0, which is not a valid http status.
I'm fetching a bundle-embedded file (in the /public folder)
example:
const response = await fetch("test.mp3", { method: "GET" }); 
// response.status should be 200 when the file exists. 

I can fetch "/test.txt" and get a http result code 200 and proper content.
When I fetch "/test.mp3" I get http result code 0. A http operation should never return status 0. Still, I can get the content of the file, if I ignore the non-ok result code.
Inspection with safari/developer network tab, security subtab,  shows "The resource was requested insecurely" for BOTH requests, although both actually succeeded . I think that this is normal, due to the way the debugger works.
I've investigated and tried NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent in Info.plist, but it didn't help (and is disrecommended anyway).
The bad result code is interfering with the operation of a library that I am using.
Explanation?

Why the downvotes?

Hmm.  3 downvotes, no explanation.  This is a great example of why SO has a bad reputation on reddit.

cause this question is missing major information. you should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

I've read it, previously and again.  It seems to me that my question has all needed information, but in case somebody doesn't know what fetch means ( I did include the fetch-api tag), I'll add the one-liner repro,

no you didn't read it cause your answer hasn't been updated to reflect what that link says. Thus the downvotes... =)

My question states the the operation gives http result 0 (which is not a valid http status, did I need to mention that?).  My answer states that for that operation (fetching an mp3 file), capacitor does not return an http result. I guess I needed to point out that "not returning an http result" means that it comes back as 0. I'll make some edits.

It turns out that, for fetches of certain media file types (extensions), Capacitor will not preserve the true http status value. Instead, it returns status 0.
This becomes apparent by reviewing the relevant Capacitor code.  It's unknown, at time of writing this answer, whether this is intentional or a unintended side effect of changes made to that code in June 2022.
A discussion of the issue can be found on the ionic forum, and a bug report has been opened on github.
